# How to generate OpenApi 3.0 spec from existing Spring Boot App?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, swagger, openapi

I have a project (Spring Boot App + Kotlin) that I would like to have an Open API 3.0 spec for (preferably in YAML). The Springfox libraries are nice but they generate Swagger 2.0 JSON. What is the best way to generate an Open Api 3.0 spec from the annotations in my controllers? Is writing it from scratch the only way?

Comment: Springfox feature request to support OpenAPI 3.0: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2022

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We have used springdoc-openapi library in our kotlin project, and it meets our need for automating the generation of API documentation using spring boot projects.

It automatically deploys swagger-ui to a spring-boot application

The Swagger UI page should then be available at:
- http://server:port/context-path/swagger-ui.html
The OpenAPI description will be available at the following url for json format:
- http://server:port/context-path/v3/api-docs

Add the library to the list of your project dependencies (No additional configuration is needed)

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.32</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: I added this dependency in pom. The jar is downloaded. It is added in maven dependencies, but I am not able to see OpenApi description at the path you mentioned. For me the path is: http://localhost:15730/context-path/v3/api-docs
Could you please assist?

Comment: "context-path" is the context of your spring application, usually it's "/" if not modified :)

Answer (score 5):

You could look at [spring-restdocs](https://spring.io/projects/spring-restdocs) and [restdocs-api-spec](https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-api-spec).

`spring-restdocs` takes a test-driven approach to API documentation which has many advantages over the introspection-driven approach spring-fox uses. `restdocs-api-spec` is an extension for spring-restdocs that adds API specification support. Currently it supports OpenAPI2 OpenAPI3 and Postman.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to implement my own generator https://github.com/jrcodeza/spring-openapi maybe you can check it out too. It's based on reflection and supports javax and spring annotations. It also generates inheritance model (with discriminators) based on Jackson annotations. Besides you can define your own interceptors if you want to alter generation process (e.g. when you have your own annotations and need to adjust generated sections of schema). You can use it in runtime mode or as a maven plugin. There is also OpenAPI3 to java client generator, which generates the model from openapi3 spec. Again it generates also Javax annotations and Jackson annotations for correct inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You can also refer to 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation
which provides a tutorial on implementing OpenAPI 3.0 with a SpringBoot 1.x or 2.x application using springdoc-openapi.

To summarize, you just add the maven dependency for springdoc-openapi into your application and when you bootRun, go to path
http://server:port/v3/api-docs.yaml/ and you will download an Open API 3.0 spec file in yaml, generated from your application's code.

You can do some other stuff with springdoc-openapi, by accessing the following when your SpringBoot application is running:

- http://server:port/v3/api-docs: Gives your spec file in Json format.
- http://server:port/swagger-ui.html: Access this in your browser and you will see the swagger documentation.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using jax-rs this tutorial helps. It uses the Apache CXF implementation. I couldn't find any other implementation of jaxrs that uses Spring Boot AND generate Open API 3.0 spec.

You'll need these depedencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-openapi-v3</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the general configuration, more detail is in the link:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = PeopleRestService.class)
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired private PeopleRestService peopleRestService;
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
    public Server jaxRsServer(Bus bus) {
        final JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        factory.setApplication(new JaxRsApiApplication());
        factory.setServiceBean(peopleRestService);
        factory.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
        factory.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(new OpenApiFeature()));
        factory.setBus(bus);
        factory.setAddress("/");
        return factory.create();
    }
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServlet() {
        final ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/api/*");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

https://dzone.com/articles/moving-with-the-times-towards-openapi-v300-adoptio

Answer (score -1):

I got it working by following these steps:

1. Edit build.gradle.kts and add this dependency:

   `implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0")`
2. White-list swagger in spring security.

   `.requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()`
3. Edit application yaml file.

```
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /openApi
```

4. Open swagger in browser by going to `http://<host>:<port>/swagger-ui/index.html`
5. Open openAPI json in browser by going to `http://<host>:<port>/openApi`
6. Download openAPI yaml by going to `http://<host>:<port>/openApi.yaml`