# How to generate MultipartFile for binary string by openapitools

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data, openapi-generator

can you, please, help me generate array/collection of `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` for files array:

```
type: array
items:
  type: string
  format: binary
```

Framework which is used: openapigenerator-cli by openapitools v.5.

Currently I only get collection of `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`.
I tried typeMappings/importMappings/mustache templates, but w/o success.

Here's library file for Spring code generation: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/languages/SpringCodegen.java.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938207/how-to-generate-openapi-3-0-spec-from-existing-spring-boot-app

Comment: Another library is used in that question

Answer (score 0):

The following workaround was used: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/pojo.mustache with `{{{datatypeWithEnum}}}` replaced with `{{#isFile}}MultipartFile{{/isFile}}{{^isFile}}{{{datatypeWithEnum}}}{{/isFile}}`, so files will be represented by given type after work of openapi-generator.